# What Does "loc:" Do In a WebPartZone's Title?

Tags: localization, web-part-zone

I know everyone does this, but I can't find an actual answer to what this does on MSDN...

When you have a `WebPartZone` defined in a page, you set the `Title` property like:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="Center" Title="loc:Center">
  ...
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

You can find plenty of examples like this on this site:

[Rendering Webpartzone is to large](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43429/rendering-webpartzone-is-to-large)

[positioning a data view web part in a body webpartzone](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45802/positioning-a-data-view-web-part-in-a-body-webpartzone)

[default custome webpart became static on custom site page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43510/default-custome-webpart-became-static-on-custom-site-page)

I assume "loc:" means localization (or perhaps it means location?). But what does this do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010 [WebPartZone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartzone.aspx) Title property is obsolete and [DisplayTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartzonebase.displaytitle.aspx) should be used instead.

Title property is declared as

```
[Obsolete("Use DisplayTitle instead.")]
    public string Title
    {
      get
      {
        return this.DisplayTitle;
      }
      set
      {
        this.HeaderText = value;
      }
    }
```

According to MSDN DisplayTitle property:

> A string that contains the title text for a zone. The default is the
>   value of the base HeaderText property.

### DisplayTitle

DisplayTitle property value could be specified as a regular string or localization string. For case of localization string the following format is used: `"loc:{ResourceKey}"`,for example `"loc:Center"`

In that case it value is retrieved by key from resource file `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.strings.resources` embedded into assembly `Microsoft.SharePoint.intl.dll`

Comment: Thanks! That's what I assumed it did, but I was unaware that it was obsolete!